# How to build the seamless bridge between two blockchain platform?

Tags: blockchain, ethereum

> How to build the bridge between two different consensus blockchain platform?

use case:

1.we need to ensure visibility of the transaction in both platforms to assure its integrity

2. When a smart contract is established on one platform, that contract can be referred to, transacted and transferred to the other platform easily and securely
3. The bridge should be able to leverage the one platform and other platform depending upon the transaction type and the TPS requirement. If it requires a faster TPS, then one consensus framework or else normal mining framework of another consensus

> How to achieve consensus on the multiple decentralized oracles?

Comment: can you be more specific about what are you trying to achieve

Comment: @mohorchatt I updated my question, please check.

Answer (score 0):

I tried researching on this.But currently no one who has a full fledge integration that you want.Basically what i understood is a multi tenant blockchain platform(with some tweaking) will address your purpose(I am not sure whether you would be achieving your 3rd requirement).

Here is a paper which could help you start on your idea.

https://arxiv.org/pdf/1901.11219.pdf